# c++11 unexpected polymorphism beahviour when using std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, polymorphism, pure-virtual

Based on [C++ polymorphism with variadic function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14996945/c-polymorphism-with-variadic-function-parameter) I tried to write similar (non-templated, with constructors) program

code:

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
    Base (int count) { run(count); } // this-> does not help

    virtual void run (int count) { // non-virtual does not help eighter
        for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
            threads.emplace_back(std::ref(*this));
    }

    virtual ~Base () {
        for (auto& t : threads)
            t.join();
    }

    virtual void operator() () = 0;

protected:
    std::vector< std::thread > threads;
};


class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    using Base::Base;
    virtual void operator() () { std::cout << "d"; }
};


int main()
{
    Derived d(4);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

expected result:

```
dddd
```

real result (Ubuntu 14.04, gcc v4.8.2):

```
pure virtual method called
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
terminate called without an active exception
dAborted (core dumped)
```

Please notice, that `Derived::operator()` was at least once really called (`d` on the last line, almost always).

Even though the code is dead simple and almost same as original (see link above) it does not work. I spent literally hours solving this problem.

Target is to construct `Derived` with a number of threads. This amount of threads will be executed (in constructor) and joined in destructor. `operator()` should be used as thread-body function (as in the original code). Moreover, it should be virtual in order to provide polymophism.

As far as I'm concerned `run` passes `*this` (for some reason) typed as `Base`, not `Derived`, so threads execute `Base::operator()` which is pure virtual

Additional question: is there any way labeling `operator()` protected?

Can anybody help me out? Thanks.

EDIT:

According to [Billy ONeal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82320/billy-oneal)'s answer I rewrote the code, so `Derived` constructor calls the `run`, but without any success

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void run (int count) { // non-virtual does not help eighter
        for (int i=0; i<count; ++i)
            threads.emplace_back(std::ref(*this));
    }

    virtual ~Base () {
        for (auto& t : threads)
            t.join();
    }

    virtual void operator() () = 0;

protected:
    std::vector< std::thread > threads;
};


class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived (int count) { run(count); }
    virtual void operator() () { std::cout << "d"; }
};


int main()
{
    Derived d(4);
    std::cout << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Results vary over the time - here are all I have ever got

```
1) d
2) dd
3) ddd
4) dddd
5) d
    pure virtual method called
    terminate called without an active exception
    ddAborted (core dumped)
```

Especially `5)` I can't explain.

I've added `{...}` around `Derived d(4);` as an anonymous block to force destructor execution before the endl of line end program termination, but since that I've got only

```
pure virtual method called
terminate called without an active exception
ddAborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I don't think the code is the same.

Comment: well, I guess it's quite similar..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code has a race condition (and therefore undefined behavior). When you start the thread in `Base`'s constructor, the thread will immediately try to call `operator()` on that object. But `Derived`'s constructor hasn't run yet, so `operator()` is still the one from `Base`, which is pure virtual. Another valid execution would be that `Base`'s constructor and `Derived`'s constructor finish before the threads actually get going, which would give the behavior you expect, but that result is unlikely.

Your comment about `this->run` not helping makes sense because the output complains about a pure virtual member function being called, and `run` is not a pure virtual member, only `operator()` is.

Comment: ok, I understand the problem, can you suggest some solution? I believe it must exist as I haven't met similar problem in other languages. Please take a look at my EDIT in the answer - it is really wierd. Thanks for helú :)

Comment: Your edited code has basically the same problem, but now when you join the threads the `Derived` destructor has already run. You need to prevent the `Derived` destructor from completing until all threads have called the virtual function. Originally you started threads running _before_ the `Derived` object's lifetime began, now you allow them to keep running _after_ the `Derived` object's lifetime ends. The threads can only call the derived function during the `Derived` object's lifetime!

Comment: @petrbel In general, it's a terrible idea to spawn a thread in the constructor of a base class - not least which because the complete object hasn't finished construction. It's better to have the client tell the object to start its thread, or to wrap the entire object creation in a factory function that starts the thread automatically after construction.

Comment: @Casey - well, I guess there is no other way than construct object without spawning threads and to do so on first call of any function that may use them - it's quite ugly but it should work, doesn't it?